# Failed resolution of imports using relative path

Tags: angular, typescript1.8, angular-cli

I have the following folder structure:

[image]

My attempt at importing language-event-subscriber in the language.component.ts is such

```
import {LanguageEventSubscriber} from './language-event-subscriber'
```

However, although the class seems to resolved in the IDE, the class is not found at runtime as evidence by failure to print its log statements.

However, the following works:

```
import './language-event-subscriber'
```

Yet in the same folder the following resolves and works at runtime

```
import {EventSubscriber, On} from "event-dispatch";
import {Language} from './language.model'

@EventSubscriber()
export class LanguageEventSubscriber {
    @On('onValidLanguage')
    onValidLanguage(language: Language) {
        console.log(language);
    }

    @On('onInvalidLanguage')
    onInvalidLanguage(status: string) {
        console.log("New status: ");
    }
}
```

Why this inconsistency?

Thanks

Comment: Could you share what's in `language-event-subscriber.ts`? Without seeing it, I suspect you're not exporting the `LanguageEventSubscriber` class in that file. Just a guess though.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation from the [event-dispatch package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/event-dispatch), even though you have `export class LanguageEventSubscriber` in your definition, this is not actually a class that is meant to be imported and consumed the same way as other modules. If you were to do it the more common way, the code that uses your module would look something like:

```js
// This is NOT the way to use this package
import  {LanguageEventSubscriber} from './language-event-subscriber';

let les = new LanguageEventSubscriber();
// ... respond to events using your variable ...
```

However, that is not how this package is meant to be used. Because of the `@EventSubscriber()` decorator in your class definition, your event handlers become available to objects of type `EventDispatcher` and are used like this:

```js
import {EventDispatcher} from "event-dispatch";
import "./language-event-subscriber";

let ed = new EventDispatcher();
ed.dispatch("onInvalidLanguage", "Sorry. That language is unavailable.");
// ... etc. ...
```

Based on [the Typescript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html), I would guess that the reason you have to import your module in this way is because it is treated like a side effect, described in the section "Import a module for side-effects only".

I don't think this is necessarily inconsistent, but it's possible that the `event-dispatch` package was coded in a non-standard way. It appears to be a relatively new package with a small number of downloads, so this is pure speculation, but it could just be that the developers of the package didn't know or chose not to follow the standard idiom for Typescript.